# Is there some sort of algorithm to continue looping through an unknown amount of child members?

Tags: c#, loops, recursion

I have the following object set up:

```
public class DrawingInstance
{
    public string DrawingNum;
    public string Rev;
    public string Title;
    public int LevelNum;
    public string RefDesc;
    public string DateRelease;
    public string DrawingType;
    public DrawingInstance ParentMember;
    public int PageInstance;

    public List<DrawingInstance> ChildMembers = new List<DrawingInstance>();
}
```

After gathering all of the data, I am currently accessing each child member one level at a time, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drawingInstance.ChildMembers.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < drawingInstance.ChildMembers[i].ChildMembers.Count; j++)
    {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

The number of levels in the file being processed can be different each time.

Is there a way through recursion to loop through and traverse an infinite number of levels? I need to process them 1 level at a time. So all of the i's will be processed, then all of the j's for each i are processed, and so on. Currently I have 10 blocks of code for processing a possible of 10 levels, but I feel like there has to be a better way to go about this.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the quick responses.
Here is a more detailed look straight from my code that gives a little more insight into how I am currently processing the objects

```
//Level 0 Pages
        int _pageNum = PageNum;
        int startIdx = 0;
        int pageCount = 0;
        pageCount = GetVisioPageCount(_treeArray.ChildMembers.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            VisioSheetOutline tempSheet = new VisioSheetOutline();
            tempSheet = GetSingleSheet(_treeArray, startIdx, _pageNum, (i + 1));
            for (int cMember = 0; cMember < tempSheet.ChildPairs.Length; cMember++)
            {
                ParentDictionary.Add(tempSheet.ChildPairs[cMember].SingleInstance, tempSheet.SheetName);
            }
            SheetList.Add(tempSheet);
            _pageNum++;
            startIdx += 15;
        }


        //Level 1 Pages
        for (int i = 0; i < _treeArray.ChildMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            pageCount = 0;
            pageCount = GetVisioPageCount(_treeArray.ChildMembers[i].ChildMembers.Count);
            startIdx = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < pageCount; j++)
            {
                VisioSheetOutline tempSheet = new VisioSheetOutline();
                tempSheet = GetSingleSheet(_treeArray.ChildMembers[i], startIdx, _pageNum, (i + 1));
                for (int cMember = 0; cMember < tempSheet.ChildPairs.Length; cMember++)
                {
                    ParentDictionary.Add(tempSheet.ChildPairs[cMember].SingleInstance, tempSheet.SheetName);
                }
                SheetList.Add(tempSheet);
                _pageNum++;
                startIdx += 15;
            }
        }

        //Level 2 Pages
        for (int i = 0; i < _treeArray.ChildMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _treeArray.ChildMembers[i].ChildMembers.Count; j++)
            {
                pageCount = 0;
                pageCount = GetVisioPageCount(_treeArray.ChildMembers[i].ChildMembers[j].ChildMembers.Count);
                startIdx = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < pageCount; k++)
                {
                    VisioSheetOutline tempSheet = new VisioSheetOutline();
                    tempSheet = GetSingleSheet(_treeArray.ChildMembers[i].ChildMembers[j], startIdx, _pageNum, (i + 1));
                    for (int cMember = 0; cMember < tempSheet.ChildPairs.Length; cMember++)
                    {
                        ParentDictionary.Add(tempSheet.ChildPairs[cMember].SingleInstance, tempSheet.SheetName);
                    }
                    SheetList.Add(tempSheet);
                    _pageNum++;
                    startIdx += 15;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am currently looking into a few of the suggestions that were made to see which one fits my particular need.

Comment: Look into `foreach`.

Comment: "Tree Traversal" is what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: You can use `recursion` or a `Stack`.

Comment: Flatten is a good term to search for.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/226162/25199 without recusion, in case you go extra deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you suggested, you can easily deal with this using recursion; you just need a recursive function:

```
public void ProcessDrawingData(DrawingInstance instance)
{
     // Do processing
     foreach (DrawingInstance d in ChildMembers)
         ProcessDrawingData(d);
}
```

Call it with the parent instance. This won't do a true breadth-first traversal though, as the first child will execute its first childs children (first all the way down) and slowly unwind.

Comment: The processing should probably be done after the recursive call...

Comment: @Smac89 He wanted "i"s before "j"s which to my interpretation was doing the processing first. It just depends on when you want to "visit" the node.

Comment: This may work, but be wary that depending on the depth of the tree, you might blow your stack doing this. The alternative is to do a `while(true)` loop to avoid a new frame. Also beware that SO exceptions vary depending on whether your platform is x86 or x64, so test both if needed. (IIRC, the x64 JIT is more likely to do a tail call optimization).

Comment: @vcsjones Of course, thats always a potential issue doing tree traversal via recursion. Thank you for the caveat though!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Ix-Main](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main) package contains a number of LINQ extensions, including the `Expand` method which will flatten a hierarchical layout:

```
IEnumerable<DrawingInstance> rootList = ...;
IEnumerable<DrawingInstance> flattened = rootList.Expand(x => x.ChildMembers);
```

Comment: Does that recursively flatten?

Comment: Yes, it is recursive.

Comment: Very cool; recursive `SelectMany`. +1 for something I didn't know about!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [foreach() statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). This will iterate through a group that you need, assuming the object implements IEnumerable.

In your case, try this:

```
foreach(DrawingInstance di in ChildMembers)
{
   // Do something with di.
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to do this repeatedly, you should have some sort of a recursive method that takes a DrawingInstance, like this:

```
public void RecursiveMethod(DrawingInstance d)
{
   foreach(DrawingInstance di in d.ChildMembers)
   {
      RecursiveMethod(di);
   }
}
```

I don't know your project, so it is up to you to figure out the base case, or if this recursive edit is what you actually want.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the original suggestion wasn't useful (since he needs to go multiple levels; not obvious from his title). With the edit, its fine, though it effectively duplicates my answer (granted, you explain `foreach` better). Also; he's using `List` so it definitely implements `IEnumerable` :) It could just be that the downvoter didn't come back to see your edit.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that's probably true. Not the best solution here, I will take that, but if my answer is incorrect I would take it down.